# What are the odds of two people with the same name having phone numbers one digit apart?

Tags: probability

I was at work and one of the ladies in the office was speaking to a man named John. While she was on the phone, another John called to speak to her. The strange thing about this is that one John's phone number was (changed for privacy) 1234 567 890 and the other's was 1234 567 891. What are the odds of this exact scenario happening? Two people, with the same name, with phone numbers that share 9 numbers in the same order, with only the final number differing and by just one.

Comment: The *exact* scenario?  In that office at that time?  It happens exactly once in the history of the universe.  You need to specify within what context.  The probability that in all possible combinations of two people that occur in the world that that or something equally notable will happen is extremely high.  Weird things happen all the time.  That it will happen *right*  exactly that way at this instant is quite small.  Assuming on in 100 people are named John it be $2$ in $1000000000$

Comment: The aspect about having the same name is probably out of scope for a math website: you'd need to know things like "what is the probability that someone's name is John." Regarding the phone number, there are $9$ possible ways to change the last digit, and there are $10^{10}$ possible 10-digit phone numbers, so if the second person's phone number is randomly chosen from all possible 10-digit numbers (excluding the first person's), then the probability is $\frac{9}{10^{10}-1}$. But this is making a lot of assumptions (are phone numbers uniform? can a phone number start with $0$?)

Comment: If you assume that all first names are equally likely and that there are exactly 50 plausible first names (for each gender), and that given any phone number $T$, both of the phone numbers $T+1$ and $T-1$ are in use, and each assigned to one person of the same gender as $T$, then the probability of at least one of the two phone numbers being assigned to the same name will be $1 - (49/50)^2 \approx (2/50).$  **However**, this fails to consider the chance that $T$ and (for example) $T+1$ would both be calling the same person, near the same time.

Comment: Under-specified problem